# Approximation of the Laplace Transform of $1 / (1+t^2)$

Tags: approximation, laplace-transform

Is there a good approximation of the Laplace transform of
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L}\left\{\frac{1}{1+t^2}\right\}=\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{1+t^2} e^{-st}~\mathrm{d}t = \mathrm{Ci}(s) \sin(s) + 1/2 \cos(s) (\pi - 2 \mathrm{Si}(s))
\end{equation}
available in analytical form for real valued $s$?

Comment: The Laplace transform is only valid for $\Re(s)>0$. Since you have an exact formula, I assume you're looking for a simpler approximate formula? Are you seeking a closed form, or would a series representation be acceptable?

Answer (score 2):

If you are concerned by rather small values of $s$, you can use the series expansion
$$ \mathrm{Ci}(s) \sin(s) +\frac 12 \cos(s) (\pi - 2 \mathrm{Si}(s))=
\frac \pi 2 \sum_{n=0}^p(-1)^n\frac {s^{2n}}{(2n)!}+\sum_{m=0}^q (-1)^{m+1}\,T_m \,s^{2m+1}$$ where the first $T_m$ are
$$\left(\begin{array}{cc}
m & T_m \\
 0 & -\log (s)-\gamma +1 \\ 1 & \frac{-6 \log (s)-6 \gamma +11}{36}  \\ 2 & \frac{-60 \log (s)-60 \gamma +137}{7200} \\ 3 & \frac{-140 \log (s)-140 \gamma +363}{705600} \\ 4 & \frac{-2520 \log (s)-2520 \gamma +7129}{914457600} \\ 5 & \frac{-27720 \log (s)-27720 \gamma +83711}{1106493696000} \\ 6 & \frac{-360360 \log (s)-360360 \gamma +1145993}{2243969215488000} \\
\end{array}\right)$$ Using the above terms, that is to say the expansion to $O(s^{14})$, the results seem to be decent up to $s=4$. At this point, the error is $0.0035$.